# Opposite of diff, sum of neighbour items of a vector

Tags: julia

Suppose, I have an array

```
x = [1, 4, 7, 8]
```

and want to calculate

```
y = [x[1]+x[2], x[2]+x[3], x[3]+x[4]] # [5, 11, 15]
```

For this, I'm doing

```
y = x[1:end-1] + x[2:end]
```

Are there better solutions, e.g. in terms of allocations and index-careful? Is there a kind of "opposite" to `diff`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is not that bad. You can speed it up with views and another alternative is to use comprehensions (all these solutions assume you are working with 1-based vectors):

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> x = rand(10^7);

julia> @btime $x[1:end-1] + $x[2:end];
  50.289 ms (6 allocations: 228.88 MiB)

julia> @btime @views $x[1:end-1] + $x[2:end];
  16.444 ms (2 allocations: 76.29 MiB)

julia> @btime [$x[i-1] + $x[i] for i in 2:length($x)];
  17.285 ms (2 allocations: 76.29 MiB)
```

For other similar operations you can consider using the RollingFunctios.jl package.

Comment: As simple as it is, this has been very helpful! @Bogumił, if I want to factor (usually by 0.5) the entire resulting vector, is there anything better than just multiply the end result?

Comment: `[0.5 * (x[i-1] + x[i]) for i in 2:length(x)]` should be faster than multiplying at he end as it will allocate less.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Bogumil's answer, in some cases, not materializing (materializing = allocating memory and setting it for whole data structure) is an option. In this case:

```
using LazyArrays

y = ApplyVector(+, @view(x[1:end-1]), @view(x[2:end]))
```

gives good timing:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> x = rand(10^7);

julia> @btime ApplyVector(+, @view(x[1:end-1]), @view(x[2:end]));
  116.360 μs (39 allocations: 2.84 KiB)

julia> @btime @views $x[1:end-1] .+ $x[2:end];
  39.102 ms (2 allocations: 76.29 MiB)
```

The time and memory saving are essentially non-comparable to the other case and much lower, but the trade-off is in slower access times. If many computations are done on all entries of summed vector, the materialized solutions are better.